# NavigationView header overlaps contents child

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have a `DrawerLayout` in which the second child is a `NavigationView`, that holds the content of the `NavigationDrawer`.

When i launch the project, opening the drawer, the `NavigationView` contents overlaps the header view set for the `NavigationView`.

The activtiy is built like following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_main_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <!-- contents of activity-->
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- nav drawer -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/navigation_drawer_header_height"
            ></RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the activity, i set the header view programmatically. I must do this because the header and the body of the nav will change during the application lifecycle.

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout headerView = new RelativeLayout(this);
        View mHeadernav =  inflator.inflate(resourceViewId,headerView);
        mNavigationView.addHeaderView(mHeadernav);
```

The `NavigationView` child's content is added in the same way, calling `addView(View)` on the `RelativeLayout` object.

Workaround: to bypass that issue, i set a value in the resources (`@dimen/header_view_height`) and i use to give the height of my header view and as a marginTop of the content of `NavigationView` child.

Another workaround that i was thinking about is create a standalone view and use it like a header view. In this case, the `RelativeLayout` (child of NavView) will have two children, the first will be the header, the second will be the content.

I know that the `NavigationView` works like `FrameLayout`, but there's a way to make the content sequantially staked like in `LinearLayout` using custom views?

Comment: Screen shot please

Comment: Have you considered just using a vertical `LinearLayout` for your drawer? It doesn't seem like you're using `NavigationView` for anything that couldn't easily be replicated with a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a `ViewGroup` inside of your `NavigationView` and inflating a header, try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_items"/>
```

Then you can define your header in the `drawer_header.xml` layout file.

Comment: I can't do this. I have to load the body and the header programmatically beacuse i need to change it in every activity